# Indexing for multiple sheets in excel with duplicate numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, row

I am trying to pull information for multiple part numbers. lets say part number 123 has 6 pieces and another order for 123 has 12 pieces. This is my formula so far, but it keeps getting an error when REF#. I think it's because in my index I need to state I want a column on a different sheet, but it throws an error every time I try. Please someone help.

{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('ODG Jobs'!A1:Q33,SMALL(IF('ODG Jobs'!C:C=B3,ROW('ODG Jobs'!C:C)),ROW('ODG Jobs'!1:33)),5)),"",INDEX('ODG Jobs'!C:C,SMALL(IF('ODG Jobs'!C:C=B3,ROW('ODG Jobs'!C:C)),ROW('ODG Jobs'!1:33)),5))}

Comment: have you tried to "evaluate the formula" to see where the error is occurring? You might be getting the error because your row/column is outside of the index area.

Comment: Step 1)   =IF(False,#N/A, INDEX('ODG Jobs'!$C:C$,23,5))                 Step 2)   =IF(False,#N/A, #REF!)                                                          Step 3) =#REF!

Comment: Just to make positive, you're *not* adding the `{}` in manually, correct?

Comment: Correct, I am hitting Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your second index formula in the if statement. From"C:C" to "A1"Q33" assuming this is the correct area. That's where the "#REF" is occuring.

Example:

{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('ODG Jobs'!A1:Q33,SMALL(IF('ODG Jobs'!C:C=B3,ROW('ODG Jobs'!C:C)),ROW('ODG Jobs'!1:33)),5)),"",INDEX('ODG Jobs'!A1:Q33,SMALL(IF('ODG Jobs'!C:C=B3,ROW('ODG Jobs'!C:C)),ROW('ODG Jobs'!1:33)),5))}

Comment: I got this to work now, Thank you that was the issue. I took part of this formula from a few different places. The original formula was used to show multiple entries for the same thing. Like part number 123 for order qty of 6 and the next line would show 12 when you lookup the part number. However, this keeps repeating the same number over and over again. so instead of showing 6 and 12 on two different lines it shows 6 then 6 then 6 then 6.

Comment: So I am still having issues with this formula. I got this to work for one column and it pulls up the information correctly, However it isn't working for the other columns. let's say the number of orders is correct.  well if one person order a red shirt and the other person ordered a blue shirt it will only say a red shirt has been ordered on both lines